# Image not found in path after mvc3 app deployed within a virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Q: the following image won't resolve as referenced from a .js script (the js script in is ~/scripts with all the other .js scripts out of the mvc3 box)

```
src: '/content/themes/base/images/down.gif'
```

This works locally but will not when deployed remotely to an iis6.0 server as a virtual directory.

I have tried:

```
src: '~/content/themes/base/images/down.gif'
```

but this wont' resolve locally or remotely.

The following will work remotely if I hard code the  virtual directory path (virtualdirectoryname is the actual virtual directory)

```
src: 'virtualdirectoryname/content/themes/base/images/down.gif'
```

Comment: What folder is your js file in?  You should just reference this with relative paths so it works in all scenarios.

Comment: script is with all other scxripts: mvc3app\Scripts\ea.droplinemenu.js

Comment: What are the actual full URLs to your web root locally and remotely?  Where is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `~` in javascript.
Try:

```
../Content/themes/base/images/down.gif
```

Comment: Does browsing directly to the image work? Lets eliminate permission issues.

Comment: Yes, the image resolves in the browser per the path, /mvc3app/content/themes/base/images/down.gif.

Comment: You mention a virtual directory. Is it setup as an application in IIS?

Comment: Yes, I have it setup as an application

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas. Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this a couple of different ways.  It looks like your best bet would be to create a Javascript function that gives you the base URL, then use that to build your paths.

Here's an example of this from http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/how-to-get-the-base-url-with-javascript:

```
function getBaseURL() {
    var url = location.href;  // entire url including querystring - also: window.location.href;
    var baseURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));


    if (baseURL.indexOf('http://localhost') != -1) {
        // Base Url for localhost
        var url = location.href;  // window.location.href;
        var pathname = location.pathname;  // window.location.pathname;
        var index1 = url.indexOf(pathname);
        var index2 = url.indexOf("/", index1 + 1);
        var baseLocalUrl = url.substr(0, index2);

        return baseLocalUrl + "/";
    }
    else {
        // Root Url for domain name
        return baseURL + "/";
    }

}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
src: getBaseURL() + '/content/themes/base/images/down.gif'
```

Comment: That gives me my base url, http://hostip and not http://hostip/virtualdir.  But what I need is my working directory.  virtualdir that maps to a working directory that houses the content.

Comment: Just modify it to pull back up to the 2nd / then.